# AWS SES Bounced Email but does not trigger AWS SNS bounce subscription and topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have some problem when integrating AWS SES into my website as it bounced every email that I sent out from the AWS EC-2 but it does not trigger the AWS SNS bounce topic and subscription that created by our own.

I also include the response that we got from the AWS SNS notification subscription. We have even requested reassociate EC-2 IP address to solve this issue but it does not stop the bounce email occurred.

P/S: The email recipient has been verified before the outgoing email is sent out. Thus, all outgoing emails are intended to send the email recipient who has agreed to receive this email. Email content does not include any spam and fraud contents.

```
  "notificationType": "Delivery",
  "mail": {
    "timestamp": "2020-12-08T08:02:45.195Z",
    "source": "qx.wong@inkrment.com",
    "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:ap-southeast-1:272232267615:identity/qx.wong@inkrment.com",
    "sourceIp": "55.77.21.130",
    "sendingAccountId": "172232267615",
    "messageId": "010e0176415fc94b-f951e6c0-5c95-47b9-9613-41a3fb974278-000000",
    "destination": [
      "trainertxt@gmail.com"
    ],
    "headersTruncated": false,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Received",
        "value": "from api@inkrment.com (ec2-55-77-21-130.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [55.77.21.130]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-3QN6IBWB7) id fIYbsPB5EHvivGZ9MG5U for trainertxt@gmail.com; Tue, 08 Dec 2020 08:02:45 +0000 (UTC)"
      },
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Tue, 8 Dec 2020 16:02:45 +0800"
      },
      {
        "name": "To",
        "value": "trainertxt@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "From",
        "value": "Inkrment Software Solution <qx.wong@inkrment.com>"
      },
      {
        "name": "Reply-To",
        "value": "qx.wong@inkrment.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Subject",
        "value": "Join us at Kuala Lumpur Exhibition"
      },
      {
        "name": "Message-ID",
        "value": "<29Yh0Xfgt6O5JGnlKrKxaUxFUzBzhlI2vpWvVFJSg@api.inkrment.com>"
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Mailer",
        "value": "PHPMailer 6.1.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)"
      },
      {
        "name": "List-Unsubscribe",
        "value": "<mailto:qx.wong@inkrment.com?subject=Unsubscribe>, <https://unsubscribe.inkrment.com?emailId=23082833473483>"
      },
      {
        "name": "List-Unsubscribe-Post",
        "value": "List-Unsubscribe=One-Click"
      },
      {
        "name": "MIME-Version",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"b1_29Yh0Xfgt6O5JGnlKrKxaUxFUzBzhlI2vpWvVFJSg\""
      },
      {
        "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
        "value": "8bit"
      }
    ],
    "commonHeaders": {
      "from": [
        "Inkrment Software Solution <qx.wong@inkrment.com>"
      ],
      "replyTo": [
        "qx.wong@inkrment.com"
      ],
      "date": "Tue, 8 Dec 2020 16:02:45 +0800",
      "to": [
        "trainertxt@gmail.com"
      ],
      "messageId": "<29Yh0Xfgt6O5JGnlKrKxaUxFUzBzhlI2vpWvVFJSg@api@inkrment.com>",
      "subject": "Join us at Kuala Lumpur Exhibition"
    }
  },
  "delivery": {
    "timestamp": "2020-12-08T08:02:46.759Z",
    "processingTimeMillis": 1564,
    "recipients": [
      "trainertxt@gmail.com"
    ],
    "smtpResponse": "250 2.0.0 OK  1607414566 s5si2013138pjz.147 - gsmtp",
    "remoteMtaIp": "172.217.194.27",
    "reportingMTA": "e232-6.smtp-out.ap-southeast-1.amazonses.com"
  }
}
```

Reputation dashboard
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the error log ?

Comment: There's no error/bounce log but the bounce rate keep raising in reputation dashboard for no reason. You may check the reputation dashboard on the original thread.

Comment: the json is for delivery event , not for bounce event. SES automatically adds the permissions to SNS trigger policy but you might want to check if you haven't modified it. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Have You configured specified configuration sets and provided list of SNS topics for all of the events(I see that Delivery was provided, but did You also provided SNS topic for bounced emails). Also does Your emails which are being sent, have enabled bounce notifications? (In SES You need to allow it explicitly for all of the notification types which You need)

Comment: I have enabled bounce notification and subscribe it with SNS but it does not trigger my bounce subscription in SNS and it increases the bounce rate in the reputation dashboard whenever I send an email out.

Comment: Do You use dedicated ip? Have You "warmed up" this IP?

Comment: It is a shared IP that issued by AWS SES

Comment: There is very strange value in the message-id header. There are two @. It should be completely modified by SES, did You do sth in order to change it?

Comment: Please ignore the alias and it is not related to the question that I am asking..